# TypeScript support in Electron

Tags: typescript, electron

Electron now supports typescript. But by running the example published in:

[Electron official blog](https://electron.atom.io/blog/2017/06/01/typescript).

I always get the following error:

[image]

Should I have done something else?

Comment: When error pop up appears, do Ctrl+C and copy then paste error instead of screenshot

Comment: can you show the `package.json` file

Comment: cannot see your codes to help you detect the issues, but mine worked. https://github.com/tim-hub/clean-hosts

Answer (score 2):

The support that they have for Typescript is that they provide definition files. At runtime you still have to run Javascript. Compile the Typescript to Javascript and then use the resulting .js file as your entry point.

Answer (score 1):

Install `ts-node` and `typescript` package to your project and then add parameter `-r ts-node/register` when running electron

```
npm install ts-node
npm install typescript

electron -r ts-node/register .
```

and add `require('ts-node/register')` in your html file

```
<script>
require('ts-node/register')
</script>
```